# Code or compiler: optimizing a IIR filter in C for the iPhone 4 and later

Tags: iphone, c, optimization, floating-point, llvm

I've been profiling my almost-finished project and I'm seeing that about three-quarters of the CPU time is spent in this IIR filter function (which is called hundreds of thousands of times in about a second currently on the target hardware) so with everything else working well I am wondering if it can be optimized for my specific hardware and software target. My targets are only iPhone 4 and newer, only iOS 4.3 and newer, only LLVM 4.x. A little bit of imprecision is probably OK if there are gains to be made.

```
static float filter(const float a, const float *b, const float c, float *d, const int e, const float x)
{
    float return_value = 0;

    d[0] = x;
    d[1] = c * d[0] + a * d[1];

    int j;

    for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) {
        return_value += (d[j] += a * (d[j + 1] - d[j - 1])) * b[j];
    }

    for (j = e + 1; j > 1; j--) {
        d[j] = d[j - 1];
    }
    return (return_value);
}
```

Any suggestions about speeding it up appreciated, also interested in your opinion if it is possible to optimize beyond the default compiler optimization at all. I am wondering if it is something where NEON SIMD would help (that is new ground for me) or if VFP can be exploited, or if LLVM autovectorization would help.

I've tried the following LLVM flags:

-ffast-math (didn't make a notable difference)

-O4 (made a big difference on the iPhone 4S with a 25% reduction in time, but no notable difference on my minimum target device the iPhone 4, improvement of which is my main goal)

-O3 -mllvm -unroll-allow-partial -mllvm -unroll-runtime -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffast-math -mllvm -vectorize -mllvm -bb-vectorize-aligned-only (LLVM autovectorization flags from Hal Finkel's slides here: http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-04-12/Slides/Hal_Finkel.pdf, made things slower than the default LLVM optimization for an Xcode release target)

Open to other flags, different approaches, and changes to the function. I'd prefer to leave the input and return types and values alone. There is actually a discussion of using NEON intrinsic functions for FIR here: https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/_media/software/optimization/neon_support_in_the_arm_compiler.pdf but I don't have quite enough experience with its subject to successfully apply the information to my own case. Thank you for any clarification.

**EDIT** My apologies for not noting this sooner. After investigating aka.nice's suggestion I noticed that the values passed in for e, a and c are always the same values and I know them before runtime, so approaches incorporating this info are an option.

Comment: Did you try to compile that function with a very recent GCC (and optimization flags, at least `-O3`)? (It could happen than a GCC 4.7 or the trunk -i.e. future 4.8- could be significantly better than LLVM).

Comment: I'm compiling with LLVM and I have tried both -O3 and -O4.

Comment: As mentioned, -O4 made a big difference on another device but unfortunately not on the specific hardware that I'm fretting about.

Comment: Is this not an IIR rather than an FIR? It appears an output `d[j]` depends in part on an earlier output `d[j-1]`. That introduces a dependency that prevents SIMD optimization and creates a bottleneck in a portion of the calculation. There are functions in the [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html) portion of the Accelerate framework (part of Mac OS and iOS) that provide functions for vector processing. You might at least be able to do portions with some of the basic routines, such as vDSP_vmul and vDSP_vma.

Comment: Oh dear, I think you may be correct. Do you think using vDSP_vmul is likely to make a significant difference?

Comment: @Halle: I addressed this in my answer.

Comment: Eric is right. This is not a FIR but an IIR. Also, you should be able to replace the last loop with a `memmove()`.

Comment: I replaced it with memmove( d + 2, d+1, sizeof( float ) * (e - 1) ); but this actually takes 10% longer than the loop.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some transformations that could be made on the code to use vDSP routines. These transformations make use of various temporary buffers named T0, T1, and T2. Each of these is an array of float with enough space for e-1 elements.

First, use a temporary buffer to compute `a * b[j]`. This changes the original code:

```
for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) {
    return_value += (d[j] += a * (d[j + 1] - d[j - 1])) * b[j];
}
```

to:

```
vDSP_vsmul(b+2, 1, &a, T0, 1, e-1);
for (j = 2; j <= e; j++)
    return_value += (d[j] += (d[j+1] - d[j-1])) * T0[j-2];
```

Then use vDSP_vmul to compute `d[j+1] * T0[j-2]`:

```
vDSP_vsmul(b+2, 1, &a, T0, 1, e-1);
vDSP_vmul(d+3, 1, T0, 1, T1, 1, e-1);
for (j = 2; j <= e; j++)
    return_value += (d[j] += T1[j-2] - d[j-1] * T0[j-2];
```

Next, promote vDSP_vmul to vDSP_vma (vector multiply add) to compute `d[j] + d[j+1] * T0[j-2]`:

```
vDSP_vsmul(b+2, 1, &a, T0, 1, e-1);
vDSP_vma(d+3, 1, T0, 1, d+2, 1, T1, 1, e-1);
for (j = 2; j <= e; j++)
    return_value += (d[j] = T1[j-2] - d[j-1] * T0[j-2];
```

I suppose I would time that and see if there is any improvement. There are some issues:

- SIMD code works best when data is 16-byte aligned. The use of array indices such as `j-1` and `j+1` prevents this. The ARM processors in phones are not as bad with unaligned data as some other processors, but performance will vary from model to model.
- If e is large (more than a few thousand), then T0 and d may be evicted from cache during the vDSP_vma operation, and the following loop will have to reload them. There is a technique called strip mining to reduce the effect of this. I will not detail it now, but, essentially, the operation is partitioned into smaller strips of the array.
- The IIR in the final loop may still bottleneck the processor. There are routines in vDSP for performing some IIRs (such as vDSP_deq22), but it is not clear whether this filter can be expressed in a way that is a good enough match to a vDSP routine to gain more performance than might be lost by the transformation.
- The summation in the final loop to calculate return_value could also be removed from the loop and replaced with a vDSP routine (likely vDSP_sve), but I suspect the slack caused by the IIR will permit the additions to be done without adding significant execution time to the loop.

The above is off the top of my head; I have not tested the code. I suggest making the transformations one-by-one so you can test the code after each change and identify any errors before going on.

If you can find a satisfactory filter that is not an IIR, more performance optimizations may be available.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I will step through it tomorrow.

Comment: @Halle: I already found one bug; note my change in the last line of the last code display. `T1[j]` was changed to `T1[j-2]`.

Comment: Hi Eric, stepping through your suggested process, on step 1. I fixed a couple of tiny typos (no vDSP_smul function but I think this should be vDSP_vsmul since a scalar and a vector are being multiplied, and missing multiplication with a in the operation) resulting in these changes: float T0[e-1];
    vDSP_vsmul(b+2, 1, &a, T0, 1, e-1);
    for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) 
        return_value += (d[j] += a * (d[j+1] - d[j-1])) * T0[j-2]; and when I listen to the output there is a mathematical change (I can hear high-pass filtering). Do you know what this might be attributable to?

Comment: No, sorry, a is part of the vDSP_vsmul call so it should not be repeated in the loop. In that case there is something else off since the output from the first step sounds heavily filtered. I'll test what is going in and out of the loop in both versions and post back.

Comment: OK, it's just changing the math -- input 1 and 2 in vDSP_vsmul aren't multiplied by each other in my function. Another way the math could be expressed is as follows:     for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) {
        float val1 = d[j + 1] - d[j - 1];
        float val2 = a * val1;
        float val3 = d[j] += val2;
        return_value += val3 * b[j];
    }

Comment: I'm experimenting with the other functions and I was wondering if you could tell me why this doesn't work as a substitute for the known-working math in my previous comment:     float tmp1[e-1];
    
    vDSP_vsbm(d+3, 1, d+1, 1, &a, 1, tmp1, 1, e-1);
   
    for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) {
        
        float val3 = d[j] += tmp1[j-2];
        float val4 = return_value + (val3 * b[j]);

        return_value = val4;
        
    } I really appreciate your input on this.

Comment: @Halle: Two problems: One, vDSP_vsbm is for vectors; it is treating `a` as a pointer to an array rather than a pointer to a scalar. You want `vDSP_vsbsm`, which is vector subtract and scalar multiply. Two, the vDSP_vsbm subtracts d[j-1] from d[j+1] using their initial values. Your original code uses a value for d[j-1] that has been updated in a previous iteration, rather than the initial value.

Comment: Got it. I guess that means there's nothing to optimize here?

Comment: @Halle: Your return value is a dot product. You can use vDSP_dotpr for that.

Comment: I'm not yet seeing the dot product in my original math due to the parentheses/order of operations, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Halle: After `d[j]` is set to some value, the code essentially has `return_value += d[j] * b[j];`.

Comment: So it does, thanks for the clarification. This is what I've written and the output seems correct, is this the proper use of the function?         d[j] += a * (d[j + 1] - d[j - 1]);
        float tmp1[1];
        vDSP_dotpr(&d[j],1,&b[j],1,tmp1,1);
        return_value += tmp1[0];

Comment: @Halle: I think that should work. You do not need to declare tmp1 as an array; just declare `float tmp1;` and pass `&tmp1`.

Comment: Strangely, this change doubled the execution time including if I moved the creation of tmp1 out of the loop and out of the function entirely -- does that seem like one possible expected outcome or is that really unexpected? Is it possible that I need to set further compiler flags in order to get optimal results with vDSP, or are we just dealing with the fact that LLVM might be working very well out of the box and other hardware optimizations are not necessarily beating it?

Comment: @Halle: What loop was `tmp1` in? It would not be in the loop that accumulates return_value, since the `vDSP_dotpr` is outside that loop, and no loop enclosing that is shown in your code? If you moved it outside of some loop that calls filter, then you may have encountered cache effects. (The elements of `b` and `d` used for the dot product would be evicted from cache after other calls to `filter`, so calling `vDSP_dotpr` later requires loading them into cache again.)

Comment: Sorry, I had vDSP_dotpr in the loop because it uses d and my understanding is that because the indices of d are updated in the loop, d can't be operated on before the loop (why I asked if it was optimizable after you explained why I couldn't use vDSP_vsbsm which operates on the same array). Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Halle: You would do vDSP_dotpr after the loop, since that is after all the values of d have been set.

Comment: Ugh, sorry about that, my head is completely in the loop approach and this is taking some mental adjustment. It's really helpful that you're taking the time to talk through it with me. I now just have the following code for the first loop, but the output is heavily changed so I think I must have made a mistake and it's eluding me so far:         for (j = 2; j <= e; j++) {
            d[j] += a * (d[j + 1] - d[j - 1]);
        }
    
        vDSP_dotpr(&d[j+2],1,&b[j+2],1,&return_value,e-1);

Comment: Wait, I got it, no j since I'm out of the loop.

Comment: OK, that has the identical timing to the original math. Thank you very much for your help though, I feel like I'm now able to apply vDSP to problems where there is a bigger win.

Comment: Do you think anything can be done with the info in my edit to my question (at its end)? Sorry to not have realized it before your comprehensive original answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd prefer to leave the input and return types and values alone…

Nevertheless, moving your rendering from float to integer would help considerably.

Localizing that change to the implementation you present won't be useful. But if you expand it to reimplement just the FIR as integer, it can quickly pay off (unless the sizes are guaranteed to always be incredibly small -- then conversion/move times cost more). Of course, moving larger portions of the render graph to integer will introduce larger gains and require even fewer conversions.

Another consideration would be to look at the utilities in Accelerate.framework (potentially saving you from writing your own asm).

Comment: Good advice but I've already moved entire the render graph to a smaller type (and it yielded great results) which is why I'm now looking elsewhere. Most of my research today suggested that for newer phones this wasn't going to make the biggest difference due to hardware FPU, is that incorrect?

Comment: @Halle: Processor execution of floating-point operations is good these days, but integer operations often still have lower latency. In various circumstances, this does not matter, because execution is fully pipelined, so the total number of operations that can be performed in a given time is nearly identical. However, the IIR aspect of your filter compels a latency in each iteration. That latency could be smaller with integer operations. Additionally, if you use smaller integers (8 or 16 bit instead of 32), more of them fit in the SIMD operations, so you can do many more in a given time.

Comment: @Halle: However, there may or may not be a good fit to integer operations. If converting to integer requires you to add scaling to compensate for the loss of floating-point, the number of extra integer operations you need may outweigh any performance gains. It depends on your situation.

Comment: @Halle if the smaller type is `float`, then size is only one aspect. my assumption was that 32 bit ints would be used, in the event you implemented it using integer (but maybe 16 is enough for your needs). floating point arithmetic is just much slower. the int/float speed ratio on ARM devices is much different from your MacBook's Intel CPU. I'm not sure what research you're referring to. Sure, it's faster than it was initially, but it's still a good bit slower. if the reports you are looking at aren't approaching the number of calculations you perform per second, it may not be very useful.

Comment: Hi justin, not sure where you're seeing confusion from me about ARM v. my desktop. One reason I'm hesitant to do a fixed-point code change with all its implications is that all the libraries that I use containing similar filters have fixed point compiler options and I've been watching the execution time saved by using them decrease per iPhone version and then start to converge with recent iPhone models + LLVM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508933 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

Comment: @Halle *"not sure where you're seeing confusion from me about ARM v. my desktop."* -- i'm not. i was trying to explain that your desktop/laptop's processor has very fast floating point arithmetic relative to integer arithmetic. on these devices, it's a different ratio and floating point calculations are still quite slow today. Neon should be much faster than VFP, but it's already on by default when targeting armv7 and armv7s so…

Answer (score 0):

I tried this little exercize to rewrite your filter with delay operator z

For example, for e=4, i renamed input u and output y

```
d1*z= u
d2*z= c*u + a*d1
d3*z= d2 + a*(d3-d1*z)
d4*z= d3 + a*(d4-d2*z)
d5*z= d4 + a*(d5-d3*z)
y = (b2*d3*z + b3*d4*z + b4*d5*z)
```

Note that the di are the filter states.
d3*z is the next value of d3 (it appears to be variable d2 in your code)
You can then eliminate the di to write the transfer function y/u in z.
You will then find that a minimal representation require only e states by factoring/simplifying above transfer function.
Denominator is `z*(z-a)^3`, that is a pole at 0, and another at a with multiplicity (e-1).

You can then put your filter in a standard state space matrix representation:

```
z*X = A*X + B*u
y = C*X + d*u
```

With the particular form of poles, you can decompose the transfer in partial fraction expansion and obtain the matrices A & B in this special form (matlab like notations)

```
A = [0 1 0 0;    B=[0;
     0 a 1 0;       0;
     0 0 a 1;       0;
     0 0 0 a]       1]
```

C & d are a bit less easy though...
They are extracted from the numerators and direct term of partial fraction expansion
They are polynomials in bi, c (degree 1) and a (degree e)
For e=4, I have

```
C=[   a^3*b2            - a^2*b3                      + a*b4 ,
     -a^2*b2              + a*b3                + (c-a^2)*b4 ,
        a*b2        + (c-a^2)*b3 + (-2*a^2*c-2*a^2-a+a^4)*b4 ,
  (c-a^2)*b2 + (-a^2-a^2*c-a)*b3 +         (-2*a*c+2*a^3)*b4 ]
d=     -a*b2            - a*c*b3                    + a^2*b4
```

If you can find the recurrence in e governing C & d, and precompute them
then the filter can be reduced to those simple vector ops:

```
z*X = a*[ 0; x2 ; x3 ; x4 ... xe ] + [x2 ; x3 ; x4 ... xe ; u ];
Y = C*[ x1 ; x2 ; x3 ; x4 ... xe ] + d*u
```

Or expressed as a function `(Xnext,y)=filter(X,u,a,C,d,e)` pseudo code:

```
y = dot_product( C , X) + d*u; // (like BLAS _DOT)
Xnext(1:e-1) = X(2:e); // this is a memcopy (like BLAS _COPY)
Xnext(e)=u;
X(1)=0;
Xnext=a*X+Xnext; // this is an inplace vector muladd (like BLAS _AXPY)

X=Xnext; // another memcopy outside the function (can be moved inside).
```

Note that if you use BLAS functions, your code will be portable to many hardwares, not just Applecentric, and I guess the perf won't be much different.

**EDIT: about partial fraction expansion**

The pure partial fraction expansion would give a diagonal state space representation, and a matrix B full of 1s. This can be an interesting variant too. (filters in parallel)
My variant used above is more like a cascade or ladder (filters in serie).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for weighing in. Am I understanding correctly that I am looking for the range of "e" that is being passed in and creating a lookup table for each integer in that range that I will preload? Could I impose on you for non-pseudocode for the example e=4?

Comment: Upon investigating your idea a bit I learned that e, a and c are always the same and I know their values before runtime.

Comment: Ideally, you would have an algorithm for computing C & d whatever a,bi,c,e (what I called reccurrence). What is the value of e?

Comment: 34 sounds very high for an IIR filter order! Even if you find the symbolic expression of integer polynomial coefficients alpha_ijk & gamma_ijk for computing C[k-e]=sum_{i=2..e,j=0..e-1} {b_i a^j (alpha_ijk a + gamma_ijk c)} for k=1..e then you must also find a numerically stable way to evaluate C[k-e], good luck... If you reach this stage, you'll also have to verify that the alternate state space representation I proposed is stable.

Comment: OK, thanks for your interesting suggestion and your feedback.